# missing elements of the array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have small problem, I have two dimensional arrays:

```
Tab1 = {1,2,3} {1,2,3} 
Tab2 = {1,2} {1,2}
```

Now I have to connect the arrays to the third array, and missing elements in a row set to zero:

```
Tab3 ={1,2,3} {1,2,3} {1,2,0} {1,2,0}
```

My code:

```
    int[][] tab1 = new int[][]{{1,2,3},{1,2,3}};
    int[][] tab2 = new int[][] {{1,2},{1,2}};
    int[][] tab = new int[tab1.length+tab2.length][];
    System.arraycopy(tab1,0,tab,0,tab1.length);
    System.arraycopy(tab2, 0, tab, tab1.length,tab2.length);

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(tab));
```

OUTPUT

```
[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2]
```

How can I set missing elements to 0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "set missing elements to 0", because they are .... *missing*.

Remember, Java arrays are fixed-size, so you cannot make an array longer. You have to create a new longer array and copy the values over. Lucky enough, the Java Library has a method for that called [`Arrays.copyOf(int[] original, int newLength)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-int:A-int-). You don't even have to fill with zeroes, as that is the default value.

So, first scan your result array `tab` for longest row length, then reallocate all short rows.

```
// Your code (unchanged, but reformatted a bit)
int[][] tab1 = { {1,2,3}, {1,2,3} };
int[][] tab2 = { {1,2}, {1,2} };
int[][] tab = new int[tab1.length + tab2.length][];
System.arraycopy(tab1, 0, tab, 0, tab1.length);
System.arraycopy(tab2, 0, tab, tab1.length, tab2.length);

// Extend short rows
int rowLen = 0;
for (int[] row : tab)
    if (row.length > rowLen)
        rowLen = row.length;
for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++)
    if (tab[i].length < rowLen)
        tab[i] = Arrays.copyOf(tab[i], rowLen);

// Print result
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(tab));
```

*Output*

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to pad `tab2` with the needed zeros prior to copying them to the new array.

```
int[][] tab1 = new int[][] {{1,2,3}, {1,2,3}};
int[][] tab2 = new int[][] {{1,2,0}, {1,2,0}}; // pad with trailing zeros
int[][] tab = new int[tab1.length+tab2.length][];
System.arraycopy(tab1, 0, tab, 0, tab1.length);
System.arraycopy(tab2, 0, tab, tab1.length, tab2.length);

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(tab));
```

Answer (score 0):

let maxLength be the maximul lenth ( lenth of a row ) of your arrays, now for all ohers arrays fill them with 0 untill you reach maxLength,

Ex : maxLenth = 3, and you have an array with rows of length 2, then you only need to add 1 zeo at the end of each row .